# DrawText FFmpeg expression on fontcolor

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to get a faded in text.  I was hoping to be able to do it via the fontcolor and an expression - like this

```
fontcolor='if(gt(n,44), white@.2, white)'
```

obviously this doesn't "fade in", but was just testing to see if it could evaluate an expression and it seems that fontcolor does not handle expressions.  Is that a factual statement - that fontcolor cannot handle expressions?

Does anybody know of a way to fade in text minus just chaining per frame? Is there a way to mask text or something to that extent?

Comment: I'm unsure if fontcolor can take an expression or not. Some filters have [timeline](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Timeline-editing) support which can allow you to use an expression to control when to enable the filter, and you can use the [`blend`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#blend) filter for the fade in.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Do you have an example on blending drawtext output? I thought you could only apply the drawtext filter to an input stream and that's it.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Never mind, I figured something out. Not pretty, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you can't use expressions for the `drawtext` filter's text color option. This makes it impossible to fade in text or do anything fancy easily.

The trick is to use a `blend` filter as LordNeckbeard suggested and overlay the original video stream with the stream that contains the subtitles. Something like this to fade in a subtitle:

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v] drawtext=fontfile=Fonts.ttf:text='test':x=100:y=50:fontcolor=white:fontsize=30 [subtitles]; [subtitles][0:v] blend=all_expr='A*(if(between(T,$start,$end),(T-$start)/($end-$start),1))+B*(1-(if(between(T,$start,$end),(T-$start)/($end-$start),1)))' [out]" -map '[out]' -map 0:a output.mp4
```

Here, `$start` and `$end` are the fade-in start and end positions in seconds, respectively. The audio stream will be taken from the input. You can copy it over with `-c:a copy`.

Answer (score 1):

ffmpeg now has the parameter `fontcolor_expr` (seen in the [ffmpeg doumentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Syntax-2)) that you can use expressions in.

Comment: Please give more information in order to have a proper answer